# How to define variables with various names?

Tags: python, variables

So I have a project that requires a lot of variables, so in order to sort them efficiently, I'm naming them with numbers, but I can't figure out how to declare variables using another variable and sth else.
Here is an example of my code

```
num = 1

while num < 10:
    num = str(num)
    'Time' + num = input('Whats the time?') #I need help on this particular line of code
    num = int(num)
    num += 1
```

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: or maybe dictionaries?

Comment: yes i have learnt about them

Comment: @xd_ then use them.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to end up with different variables `time1`, `time2` etc.

You could use a dictionary to store your variables:

```
num = 1
results= {}  # create empty dictionary

while num < 10:
    num = str(num)
    results[f"time{num}"]  # will name the keys like time1, time2 etc.
    num = int(num)
    num += 1
```

You can then access the variables via

`results["time1"]`
etc.

Comment: Thank you, as I am still not too familiar with python, while I do know about dictionaries, I'm not very sure how to use them.

Comment: you can find some usage examples [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)